# .NET MVC Controller action not invoked by GET or POST from Flex app

Tags: .net, apache-flex, model-view-controller, post, get

A flex app running in a view of my .NET MVC app can load data fine from another route, but submitting data via either POST or GET never invokes the controller action. Interestingly, the only way I can get the action method to fire is by passing intentionally malformed post variables in the http request. Odd.

Content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and I have set authentication to "None" in web.config with no improvement. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the contents of the GET or POST by using something like Firebug:

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com)